# Having trouble importing javascript framework for use in Typescript class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, svg.js

I'm trying to load `SVG.js` as a module so that I can utilize it within a typescript class, within an external namespace module.

I have the `SVG.js` type definitions file loaded. The original `SVG.js` file remains as pure JavaScript.

I cannot figure out how to import the `SVG.js` as a module so I can use it within my class. I've tried a number of import definitions and none seem to work.

What is the correct way to import a JavaScript library for use within a Typescript class?

**I've tried:**

```
import * as svg from '../../Libraries/svg-2.6.3.js';
```

Gives error "... is not a module"

```
import svg = require('../../Libraries/svg-2.6.3.js');
```

Gives error "...d.ts is not a module"

```
import '../../Libraries/svg-2.6.3.js';
```

Causes namespace references to be underlined in red, with "Cannot find name" errors.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed https://www.npmjs.com/package/svg.js you simply need to:

```
import 'svg.js'
```

## More

The name of the import matches the name of the npm module you installed (`npm install svg.js`)

Comment: When I do that, all my types referenced in that file throw "cannot find name..." typescript errors.

Comment: Make sure the module is `npm install`ed. Check tsconfig has `module: commonjs`.